# how to generate random int value using System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: c#, random, cryptography

i want to generate random int values using System.Security.Cryptography  from 0 to 26 how can i do that ? i know can use system.random to do this but i want to use System.Security.Cryptography

Answer (score 8):

You can use this to generate a random int from a Crypto RNG.  However, I'd be hard pressed to explain a scenario, outside of cryptography, where such a tool is useful.

```
RNGCryptoServiceProvider CprytoRNG = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

// Return a random integer between a min and max value.
int RandomIntFromRNG(int min, int max)
{
    // Generate four random bytes
    byte[] four_bytes = new byte[4];
    CprytoRNG.GetBytes(four_bytes);

    // Convert the bytes to a UInt32
    UInt32 scale = BitConverter.ToUInt32(four_bytes, 0);

    // And use that to pick a random number >= min and < max
    return (int)(min + (max - min) * (scale / (uint.MaxValue + 1.0)));
}
```

Comment: Aside from the typo in `CprytoRNG` ("crytpo" is my usual offender) the preferred way is to use `RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` instead of depending on the RNGCryptoServiceProvider type directly (unless you're concerned with the factory having been repointed to a non-CSPRNG via CryptoConfig).  RandomNumberGenerator.Create() exists on .NET Core, but the RNGCryptoServiceProvider class does not.

Comment: Unit tested and found values 0,9 never generates 9 due to https://www.dotnetperls.com/cast-int
Ended up with the following code: `(int)Math.Round(min + (max - min) * (scale / (uint.MaxValue + 1.0)), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] four_bytes = new byte[4];             

System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create().GetBytes(four_bytes);

uint rand = BitConverter.ToUInt32(four_bytes, 0);

//range is 0 to 2^32-1, divide some number to limit it to the range you want
```

Comment: Since the desire is for *secure* random numbers, that last step that you've only got as a comment is critical.

Answer (score -2):

Then you should use [`RandomNumberGenerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx) class for that purpose. But per what you have posted 
*from 0 to 26* I believe you should be using `Random` class for that purpose.

For your specific purpose to generate a cryptographic strong random numbers you should use [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) class which inherits from `RandomNumberGenerator` class and provides mechanism for generating cryptographic random numbers instead of using `RandomNumberGenerator` class directly.

You can see an example in the linked MSDN documentation.

Comment: @ArtjomB., it is using one of the provider class `RNGCryptoServiceProvider `. See edited answer. But yes it's as straight forward as using `Random` class.

Comment: Yes, the example is the kicker, but you should describe in general how it is done.

Comment: Poster should not use Random() because he wants to generate a number fom 0 to 26. The range does not dictate the methodology, the use does. If he needs a highly random value in that range he should use System.Security.Cryptography to do it. Anon Coward's reply is a good example to work with.